# Time interval - I want something to happen every x milliseconds (Arduino-not relevant)

Tags: time, arduino, intervals

So I have a piece of code that do something every 12 seconds.

```
unsigned long currentMillis, previousMillis;

void loop()
{
unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  time = currentMillis - previousMillis;

    if(time >= 0 && time <=40 ) //about this "40" I say below
      {
       do stuff;
      }

    if (time =="12 seconds"+/- 40  <- example)  previousMillis = currentMillis; //reset

}
```

So it goes 0,1,2,3,4....12.000,0,1,2,3...,12.000,0,1,2 and so on
(I know it isn't exactly 12.000 and not every number is consecutive but this is an example)

And my problem is:
In this interval 0-12.000 I want to do something else every x seconds (x not bigger that 12sec) 
I printed in serial monitor currentMillis , time , previousMillis and it looks like this:

```
  currentMillis: 1   time: 1   previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 5   time: 5   previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 13  time: 13  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 21  time: 21  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 30  time: 30  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 38  time: 38  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 47  time: 47  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 56  time: 56  previousMillis  0

.....................................................
.....................................................
.....................................................
.....................................................

  currentMillis: 12536  time: 12536  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 12547  time: 12547  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 12556  time: 12556  previousMillis  0
  currentMillis: 12565  time: 12565  previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12575  time: 10     previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12585  time: 20     previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12595  time: 30     previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12605  time: 40     previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12614  time: 49     previousMillis  12565
  currentMillis: 12624  time: 59     previousMillis  12565
```

//when I want to catch 12.000ms I use a little interval like +/- 40 in an IF statement just to be sure I catch 12sec time.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need a solution to execute something each 12 seconds and you think that 40 msec is a limit to stay into this time. I think the code below is a solution. It uses the Arduino environment functions `setup()` and `loop()`.

I've used your idea of the 40 msec, but it's my opinion that it's better to avoid to use this kind of corrections, and it's better to use something that adjusts the time for the "next" loop (see comment in the code below).

```
static unsigned long timer=0,msec=0;

void setup() {
    msec=millis();
}

void loop(void)
{
    timer-=msec;
    msec=millis();
    timer+=msec;

    if (timer>=12000-40) {
        //Do something
        timer=0;

        //To solve the time oscillation you might use the code below
        //and you correct the if as if (timer>=12000)
        //timer=timer-12000; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define some function to increase readability.
You store the next time to do your action.
You can do a function for each frequency. For example DELAY1 12000 and DELAY2 1234;

```
static void funct1(unsigned long now) {
  static unsigned long next;
  if (next > now)
    return;
  next = now + DELAY1;
/* here your code */
}
static void funct2(unsigned long now) {
  static unsigned long next;
  if (next > now)
    return;
  next = now + DELAY2;
/* here your code */
}


loop() {
  unsigned long now = millis();
  funct1(now);
  funct2(now);
}
```